# Google Calendar Api not asking for Oauth Screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, oauth, google-calendar-api

I have recently used `Google Calendar API.`

I have Created Project and Generated Credential.

For localhost i used following Credential :

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "xxxxxx-00000",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost" ]
  }}
```

It was asking for Oauth and working fine as well.

But when i wanted to make request from web server i changed credential and it was :

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "xxxxxxxx-99999",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "http://demo.mydemo.com" ],
    "javascript_origins": [ "http://demo.mydemo.com" ]
  }}
```

But neither it is redirecting for Oauth (Authentication) nor asking for permission, and not even throwing any error/exception.

Comment: What happens if you don't change credentials? change only origin and redirect_uri.

Comment: I tried using various Ways but none is helping me, and if i'm on wrong way then it should promt me error but there in no error and main thing, it is not redirecting me to authenticate even.