# GMail OAUTH not asking for permission when published

Tags: json, oauth, token, gmail-api

I've started using the GMail API and it's working fine on my local machine; it will open the Google permissions page and I can select my account. It then stores the return json token and only asks again if this token is removed.

When I publish to the server, the OAUTH page is never displayed and the application appears to timeout with a 'Thread was being aborted' exception.

My code;

```
    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/credentials/client_id.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/credentials/gmail_readonly_token.json");

            _credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            db.writeLog("INFO", "Gmail Credentials Saved","Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

        }
        // Create Gmail API service.
        service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        db.writeLog("Error", "Failure when creating Gmail class", e.Message, null, _username, null);
    }
```

Is there something I need to change within the 'client_id.json' (formally client_secret.json) file? The only thing I have altered is the redirect_uris line.

Any other suggestions would be welcome, the only other question I could find that is similar is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436251/google-calendar-api-not-asking-for-oauth-screen) but there is no answer.

Thanks,

Danny.

Answer (score 0):

The first one worked because you followed the intended use case, which is client-side. But, to implement authorization on the server, follow the [Implementing Server-Side AUthorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) guide.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response!  I'll give this a go, I was struggling to see the difference between a web application running in IIS Express and a web application running in IIS on the server, especially when the server application pool has been set to run as me.  Cheers!